# Add image on top of Highcharts Gauge

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am having problems adding an image to the Highcharts gauge.

Ideally I would like to add a glyphicon on top of the gauge. See JSFiddle:

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rb9c8vrr/69/#&togetherjs=UneywfE7tJ)

```
labels: {
  items: [{
    html: '<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">icon</div>',
    style: {
      top: '80px',
      left: '170px',
      fontSize: '20px',
      margin: '0 auto',
      width: '100px'
    }
  }]
}
```

I have used a label, the text in the label is displayed so I know the label is working, but when I remove the text in the label the glyphicon does not show.

I have also experimented with adding an image in case the glyphicon does not work (see the same JSFiddle sun image), but I can not get the image to appear on top of the gauge, when the image is positioned correctly over the gauge it is displayed behind the gauge and is not visible. How can I bring the image to the front?

```
function (chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.image('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png', 70, 130, 30, 30)
        .add();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can extract the center position from the formula:  chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth / 2) - (imageWidth / 2). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2nLfegwb/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! Any idea why the Glyphicon is not working?

Comment: Because the labels converts HTML into SVG elements, so HTML does not exists in DOM.